# TypeError: asm.js type error: Disabled by debugger

Tags: javascript, firefox, asm.js

I'm trying to run a asm.js code in Firefox 29 but I get this warning from debugger console:

```
TypeError: asm.js type error: Disabled by debugger
```

Here is the code:

```
function boo() {
    "use asm";

    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i = (i + 1) | 0) {
        var result = result + i | 0;
    }
}
```

It seems the asm.js is disable when I work with it, How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Asm.js optimizations aren't possible when the debugger is running. It will fallback to be executed as normal JS and can debugged that way. In which sense do you want to work with asm.js code?

Comment: While learning asm. I'm trying to learn asm using JS Bin. And while my js is working, I have no idea if it's valid asm without seeing the console warnings.